# Mysql installation error (unmet dependencies)

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I just wanted to re-install the mysql from my ubuntu. So i have purge the mysql but when i am trying to install it. It's show dependencies unmet error.

```
    sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.17.10.1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-testsuite-5.7 : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 (= 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When i try to update it shows:-

```
     sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-kernel-team/pti/ubuntu artful InRelease
  403  Forbidden
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty Release
Hit:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mutlaqja/ppa/ubuntu artful InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-kernel-team/pti/ubuntu/dists/artful/InRelease  403  Forbidden
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

When i try to fix dependency the problem we get is still the same:-

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.7
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 105 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3,189 kB of archives.
After this operation, 48.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-5.7 amd64 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 [3,189 kB]
Fetched 3,189 kB in 0s (14.9 MB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 158292 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb ...
grep: /etc/mysql/: No such file or directory
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.22-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

none of the fix works for me.

Thanks in advance :)
Happy coding

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: oh sorry for that

Comment: Yep, this question is better located at Ask Ubuntu. Post your stuff there and you should get help quickly.

Comment: need to wait 20min to post a question. :3

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. It also resets the question's score. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score -1):

Seems your system is stuck in the process of mysql. Restart your system and run the following code.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt purge -y mysql-server
sudo apt install -y mysql-server
```

Then you should be prompted by the mysql installer to provide a password and it should work just fine.

Comment: Sorry, it's giving me the same issue. Thanks for help anyways